# ArcPy MosaicToNewRaster problem

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, mosaic

I can't seem to get the mosaic created for this.

```
 import arcpy

 arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\projectTemp\FloodAnalysis\output\2yr\raster"
 arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
 srName = r"C:\projectTemp\FloodAnalysis\output\2yr\raster"
 outPut = r"C:\projectTemp\FloodAnalysis\output\2yr"
 rasterName = "2ft.img"
 bands = 1
 method = "First"
 clMap = "First"

 arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(srName, outPut, rasterName, "", "", "", bands,      "First", "First")
```

Comment: so what happens? nothing? error? empty output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enter the parameters in the correct order when using Python.  From the [ArcGIS 10.2 help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000098000000), the following is the correct format:

```
MosaicToNewRaster_management (input_rasters, output_location, raster_dataset_name_with_extension, {coordinate_system_for_the_raster}, {pixel_type}, {cellsize}, number_of_bands, {mosaic_method}, {mosaic_colormap_mode})
```

Usually, you bring a list of rasters in the following type of comma-separated list:

```
[inputRasters, ...]
```

You can use arcpy.ListRasters() to produce a list of all of the rasters in your workspace that you would like to mosaic:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\projectTemp\FloodAnalysis\output\2yr\raster"
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()
```

And to put it all together (In this untested script):

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\projectTemp\FloodAnalysis\output\2yr\raster"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Local Variables
outPut = r"C:\projectTemp\FloodAnalysis\output\2yr"
name = "yourOutput.img"
"""Note, there are multiple ways to define a spatial reference,
here I am pointing to a .prj"""
sr = r"C:\path\to\prj\file.prj"
bands = 1
method = "First"
clMap = "First"

# Create raster list
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(rasters, outPut, name, sr, "", "", bands, method, clMap)
```